# Why does it take so long to deploy a nodejs app on GAE flex vm?

Tags: app-engine-flexible

It always takes more than 5-6 minutes to update a GAE node app with a new version. I am probably doing something wrong and not sure how I can speed up deployments?

Answer (score 4):

You're probably not doing anything wrong.  Unfortunately 5-6 minutes is not uncommon for flex deployments and we are actively working on improving that.

Comment: Is this still something that is actively being worked on?

Comment: year later, probably not  a priority

Comment: @AlexMilstead @Ben In 2019 for me it takes ~10 min for 1 page server with 10 dependencies where 5 of them are `@google-cloud/...`